# where to get certificates for font request?

Tags: android

I've been reviewing the official documentation for adding the EmojiCompa library here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat . It has this code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     FontRequest fontRequest = new FontRequest(
       "com.example.fontprovider",
       "com.example",
       "emoji compat Font Query",
       CERTIFICATES);
     EmojiCompat.Config config = new FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(this, fontRequest);
     EmojiCompat.init(config);
   }
}
```

but it doesn't have any information on where/how to retrieve CERTIFICATES. I checked the font request section and wasn't able to find anything there either.

EDIT: To clarify, I see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="certs">
       <item>MIIEqDCCA5CgAwIBAgIJA071MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMIGUMQsww...</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

But do not see any information on where `MIIEqDCCA5CgAwIBAgIJA071MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMIGUMQsww...` is retrieved, especially with regards to EmojiCompat.

Comment: Why do you say "it doesn't have any information on where/how to retrieve CERTIFICATES. I checked the font request section and wasn't able to find anything there either."? It's right here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#adding-certificates

Comment: I assume you read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#adding-certificates ?

Comment: @JosephSible yes. I should have clarified what information I'm missing. I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: What font provider are you using? It it preinstalled? Are you using the support library?

Comment: @JosephSible sorry. I'm quite new to Android development and my only experience with font providers is through web, where I easily can copy and paste some css and I'm good to go.  Here, I'm only interested in getting EmojiCompat as in the original link to load, and figured that the documentation would have the kind of coverage I'm used to with documentation for web tech.

Comment: Did you got the answer? Where should get that free cert for free fonts? I also wanna use emojis.

Answer (score 4):

You can add certificates via Android Studio

1. Tap on some view in your XML file such as `MaterialButton`
2. Switch the `Code` tab to `Design`
3. Scroll to `All attributes` open it and click on `fontFamily` attribute dropdown
4. Pick `More Fonts`
5. Choose one of the downloadable fonts and Android Studio creates for you `font_certs.xml` in your values folder

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in Application class in onCreate() method.
`EmojiCompat.Config config = new BundledEmojiCompatConfig(this); EmojiCompat.init(config);`

Answer (score -2):

Answer inspired by : [Custom and Downloadable Fonts on Android](https://www.raywenderlich.com/213-custom-and-downloadable-fonts-on-android#toc-anchor-009)

Follow the steps to add a certificate [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#adding-certificates)

Then replace **CERTIFICATES** with **R.array.certs** like so, where R.array.certs is the name of the certificate you added.

`val fontRequest = FontRequest(
                "com.example.fontprovider",
                "com.example",
                "emoji compat Font Query",
                R.array.certs
        )`